# Name lookup after qualified declarator-id

Tags: c++, class, language-lawyer

Sec. 3.4.3/3 said:

> In a declaration in which the declarator-id is a qualified-id, names
>   used before the qualified-id being declared are looked up in the
>   defining namespace scope; names following the qualified-id are looked
>   up in the scope of the member’s class or namespace.

There is a code example from 3.4.3/3 N3797:

```
class X { };
class C {
    class X { };
    static const int number = 50;
    static X arr[number];
};
X C::arr[number];// ill-formed:
                 // equivalent to: ::X C::arr[__C::number__];
                 // not to: C::X C::arr[__C::number__];
```

But I think that it is not true because unqualified name used in the `X C::arr[number]` can be found in the enclosing scope, but the `X C::arr[C::number]` is not searching the `number` in the enclosing scopes. Is it a typo?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're asking here. Are you questioning how C::number is resolved in the outer scope?

Comment: I think the paragraph before lays out the rule well if you think about it for a second, you should probably include that text as well since it make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson No, I know how C::number is resolved in the outer scope. The name `number` cannot be found in the `C`'s enclosing scope. I want to clarify that `X C::arr[number];` is not equivalent to `::X C::arr[C::number];`, but equivalent to `::X C::arr[number];`. Is it a typo in the Standard?

Comment: The example is correct based on what compilers actually do and what is reasonable to expect of compilers. They see `X` before they see the `C::`, and they need to be able to resolve `X` before continuing parsing to prevent all sorts of issues when `X` may or may not be a template. But I cannot say right now whether the normative text of the standard manages to agree with this.

Comment: On my phone, so i can't write a proper answer - the problem is not number, it's X. The names before qualified-id are looked up from declaration's scope, so global X is found. ::X C::arr[X::number] is thus ill-formed because C::arr does not refer to a previously declared entity.

Comment: Note: the text in N3797 does not contain the underscores that appear in OP's quoted code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell example is correct and follows directly from the the paragraph before the example:

> In a declaration in which the declarator-id is a qualified-id, **names
>   used before the qualified-id** being declared are **looked up in the
>   defining namespace scope**;

So the `X` found will be `::X` and not `C::X` since it is before the qualified-id

and:

> **names following** the qualified-id are **looked
>   up in the scope of the member’s class or namespace**

So `number` will be `C::number` since it is after the qualified-id.

Comment: But `::X C::arr[C::number]` is not equivalent to `X C::arr[number]` as said in the comment.

Comment: `X C::arr[number]` equivalent to `::X C::arr[number]` in the example's context.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv *In the context of the example*, `number` and `C::number` are equivalent, because `C::number` exists. If `C::number` didn't exist, but `::number` does, then of course `C::number` and `::number` aren't equivalent, but the example doesn't attempt to claim otherwise.